# Azure Automation Update Managemet schedules can be removed using powershell, but they still exist in the portal

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-log-analytics

If I used Get-AzAutomationSchedule for my automation account, I get nothing in return because I used Remove-AzAutomationSchedule for all of them. But if I look in the portal, every schedule I've deployed is there present. If I select a schedule that I've removed using Powershell and then attempt to update the schedule in the portal, I get the crying rain cloud and it says

```
NewScheduleBladeV2
MICROSOFT_AZURE_AUTOMATION
NewScheduleBladeV2
```

The reacurrance is also listed as unknown in the list.

This is a problem not only for clarity when viewing in the portal, but if I attempt to run my ARM template again with the schedules there, I get an "Internal Server Error" code 500. I can't redeploy them if I delete them with Powershell.

Is there anyway to send something to Azure to update these? Not sure if I need to do some API call or some form of Set-Az cmdlet

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the issue you are facing but all worked good for me when i used cmdlets Get-AzAutomationSchedule and Remove-AzAutomationSchedule of Az.Automation module versioned 1.2.1.

Is this still an issue at your end ? If yes, can you restart the browser after clearing the cache and deleting the cookies ?